# jCarousel dynamically changing the number of items scrolled on window resize

Tags: jcarousel

We are using the the new jCarousel and wanted to dynamically change the number of scrolled items if user resizes the window. Can this be achieved. We have looked at the documentation but cannot figure out if this is possible.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

> $( window ).resize(function() {});

and

> visible: x

Documentation for JQuery .resize() can be found here: https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Here is more info about changing the number of visible items in a jcarousel: [Setting number of visible images in jCarousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122426/setting-number-of-visible-images-in-jcarousel)

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#Carousel").jcarousel({
            visible: 2
      });

      $( window ).resize(function() {
            $("#Carousel").jcarousel({
                    visible: 5                    
            });
      });
});
```