# Allowing more than three items in jCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jcarousel

I have the same problem as the following question:

[Setting number of visible images in jCarousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122426/setting-number-of-visible-images-in-jcarousel)

The answer seems to be in the CSS file, but the website that has basically been dropped on me does not seem to follow the norm.

Here is my .js code:

```
/*!
 * jCarousel - Riding carousels with jQuery
 *   http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2006 Jan Sorgalla (http://sorgalla.com)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 * and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
 *
 * Built on top of the jQuery library
 *   http://jquery.com
 *
 * Inspired by the "Carousel Component" by Bill Scott
 *   http://billwscott.com/carousel/
 */

(function (g) { var q = { vertical: !1, rtl: !1, start: 1, offset: 1, size: null, scroll: 6, visible: 6, animation: "normal", easing: "swing", auto: 0, wrap: null, initCallback: null, setupCallback: null, reloadCallback: null, itemLoadCallback: null, itemFirstInCallback: null, itemFirstOutCallback: null, itemLastInCallback: null, itemLastOutCallback: null, itemVisibleInCallback: 6, itemVisibleOutCallback: 6, animationStepCallback: null, buttonNextHTML: "<div></div>", buttonPrevHTML: "<div></div>", buttonNextEvent: "click", buttonPrevEvent: "click", buttonNextCallback: null, buttonPrevCallback: null, itemFallbackDimension: null }, m = !1; g(window).bind("load.jcarousel", function () { m = !0 }); g.jcarousel = function (a, c) { this.options = g.extend({}, q, c || {}); this.autoStopped = this.locked = !1; this.buttonPrevState = this.buttonNextState = this.buttonPrev = this.buttonNext = this.list = this.clip = this.container = null; if (!c || c.rtl === void 0) this.options.rtl = (g(a).attr("dir") || g("html").attr("dir") || "").toLowerCase() == "rtl"; this.wh = !this.options.vertical ? "width" : "height"; this.lt = !this.options.vertical ? this.options.rtl ? "right" : "left" : "top"; for (var b = "", d = a.className.split(" "), f = 0; f < d.length; f++) if (d[f].indexOf("jcarousel-skin") != -1) { g(a).removeClass(d[f]); b = d[f]; break } a.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "UL" || a.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "OL" ? (this.list = g(a), this.clip = this.list.parents(".jcarousel-clip"), this.container = this.list.parents(".jcarousel-container")) : (this.container = g(a), this.list = this.container.find("ul,ol").eq(0), this.clip = this.container.find(".jcarousel-clip")); if (this.clip.size() === 0) this.clip = this.list.wrap("<div></div>").parent(); if (this.container.size() === 0) this.container = this.clip.wrap("<div></div>").parent(); b !== "" && this.container.parent()[0].className.indexOf("jcarousel-skin") == -1 && this.container.wrap('<div class=" ' + b + '"></div>'); this.buttonPrev = g(".jcarousel-prev", this.container); if (this.buttonPrev.size() === 0 && this.options.buttonPrevHTML !== null) this.buttonPrev = g(this.options.buttonPrevHTML).appendTo(this.container); this.buttonPrev.addClass(this.className("jcarousel-prev")); this.buttonNext = g(".jcarousel-next", this.container); if (this.buttonNext.size() === 0 && this.options.buttonNextHTML !== null) this.buttonNext = g(this.options.buttonNextHTML).appendTo(this.container); this.buttonNext.addClass(this.className("jcarousel-next")); this.clip.addClass(this.className("jcarousel-clip")).css({ position: "relative" }); this.list.addClass(this.className("jcarousel-list")).css({ overflow: "hidden", position: "relative", top: 0, margin: 0, padding: 0 }).css(this.options.rtl ? "right" : "left", 0); this.container.addClass(this.className("jcarousel-container")).css({ position: "relative" }); !this.options.vertical && this.options.rtl && this.container.addClass("jcarousel-direction-rtl").attr("dir", "rtl"); var j = this.options.visible !== 6 ? Math.ceil(this.clipping() / this.options.visible) : null, b = this.list.children("li"), e = this; if (b.size() > 0) { var h = 0, i = this.options.offset; b.each(function () { e.format(this, i++); h += e.dimension(this, j) }); this.list.css(this.wh, h + 100 + "px"); if (!c || c.size === void 0) this.options.size = b.size() } this.container.css("display", "block"); this.buttonNext.css("display", "block"); this.buttonPrev.css("display", "block"); this.funcNext = function () { e.next() }; this.funcPrev = function () { e.prev() }; this.funcResize = function () { e.resizeTimer && clearTimeout(e.resizeTimer); e.resizeTimer = setTimeout(function () { e.reload() }, 100) }; this.options.initCallback !== null && this.options.initCallback(this, "init"); !m && g.browser.safari ? (this.buttons(!1, !1), g(window).bind("load.jcarousel", function () { e.setup() })) : this.setup() }; var f = g.jcarousel; f.fn = f.prototype = { jcarousel: "0.2.8" }; f.fn.extend = f.extend = g.extend; f.fn.extend({ setup: function () { this.prevLast = this.prevFirst = this.last = this.first = null; this.animating = !1; this.tail = this.resizeTimer = this.timer = null; this.inTail = !1; if (!this.locked) { this.list.css(this.lt, this.pos(this.options.offset) + "px"); var a = this.pos(this.options.start, !0); this.prevFirst = this.prevLast = null; this.animate(a, !1); g(window).unbind("resize.jcarousel", this.funcResize).bind("resize.jcarousel", this.funcResize); this.options.setupCallback !== null && this.options.setupCallback(this) } }, reset: function () { this.list.empty(); this.list.css(this.lt, "0px"); this.list.css(this.wh, "10px"); this.options.initCallback !== null && this.options.initCallback(this, "reset"); this.setup() }, reload: function () { this.tail !== null && this.inTail && this.list.css(this.lt, f.intval(this.list.css(this.lt)) + this.tail); this.tail = null; this.inTail = !1; this.options.reloadCallback !== null && this.options.reloadCallback(this); if (this.options.visible !== null) { var a = this, c = Math.ceil(this.clipping() / this.options.visible), b = 0, d = 0; this.list.children("li").each(function (f) { b += a.dimension(this, c); f + 1 < a.first && (d = b) }); this.list.css(this.wh, b + "px"); this.list.css(this.lt, -d + "px") } this.scroll(this.first, !1) }, lock: function () { this.locked = !0; this.buttons() }, unlock: function () { this.locked = !1; this.buttons() }, size: function (a) { if (a !== void 0) this.options.size = a, this.locked || this.buttons(); return this.options.size }, has: function (a, c) { if (c === void 0 || !c) c = a; if (this.options.size !== null && c > this.options.size) c = this.options.size; for (var b = a; b <= c; b++) { var d = this.get(b); if (!d.length || d.hasClass("jcarousel-item-placeholder")) return !1 } return !0 }, get: function (a) { return g(">.jcarousel-item-" + a, this.list) }, add: function (a, c) { var b = this.get(a), d = 0, p = g(c); if (b.length === 0) for (var j, e = f.intval(a), b = this.create(a); ; ) { if (j = this.get(--e), e <= 0 || j.length) { e <= 0 ? this.list.prepend(b) : j.after(b); break } } else d = this.dimension(b); p.get(0).nodeName.toUpperCase() == "LI" ? (b.replaceWith(p), b = p) : b.empty().append(c); this.format(b.removeClass(this.className("jcarousel-item-placeholder")), a); p = this.options.visible !== null ? Math.ceil(this.clipping() / this.options.visible) : null; d = this.dimension(b, p) - d; a > 0 && a < this.first && this.list.css(this.lt, f.intval(this.list.css(this.lt)) - d + "px"); this.list.css(this.wh, f.intval(this.list.css(this.wh)) + d + "px"); return b }, remove: function (a) { var c = this.get(a); if (c.length && !(a >= this.first && a <= this.last)) { var b = this.dimension(c); a < this.first && this.list.css(this.lt, f.intval(this.list.css(this.lt)) + b + "px"); c.remove(); this.list.css(this.wh, f.intval(this.list.css(this.wh)) - b + "px") } }, next: function () { this.tail !== null && !this.inTail ? this.scrollTail(!1) : this.scroll((this.options.wrap == "both" || this.options.wrap == "last") && this.options.size !== null && this.last == this.options.size ? 1 : this.first + this.options.scroll) }, prev: function () { this.tail !== null && this.inTail ? this.scrollTail(!0) : this.scroll((this.options.wrap == "both" || this.options.wrap == "first") && this.options.size !== null && this.first == 1 ? this.options.size : this.first - this.options.scroll) }, scrollTail: function (a) { if (!this.locked && !this.animating && this.tail) { this.pauseAuto(); var c = f.intval(this.list.css(this.lt)), c = !a ? c - this.tail : c + this.tail; this.inTail = !a; this.prevFirst = this.first; this.prevLast = this.last; this.animate(c) } }, scroll: function (a, c) { !this.locked && !this.animating && (this.pauseAuto(), this.animate(this.pos(a), c)) }, pos: function (a, c) { var b = f.intval(this.list.css(this.lt)); if (this.locked || this.animating) return b; this.options.wrap != "circular" && (a = a < 1 ? 1 : this.options.size && a > this.options.size ? this.options.size : a); for (var d = this.first > a, g = this.options.wrap != "circular" && this.first <= 1 ? 1 : this.first, j = d ? this.get(g) : this.get(this.last), e = d ? g : g - 1, h = null, i = 0, k = !1, l = 0; d ? --e >= a : ++e < a; ) { h = this.get(e); k = !h.length; if (h.length === 0 && (h = this.create(e).addClass(this.className("jcarousel-item-placeholder")), j[d ? "before" : "after"](h), this.first !== null && this.options.wrap == "circular" && this.options.size !== null && (e <= 0 || e > this.options.size))) j = this.get(this.index(e)), j.length && (h = this.add(e, j.clone(!0))); j = h; l = this.dimension(h); k && (i += l); if (this.first !== null && (this.options.wrap == "circular" || e >= 1 && (this.options.size === null || e <= this.options.size))) b = d ? b + l : b - l } for (var g = this.clipping(), m = [], o = 0, n = 0, j = this.get(a - 1), e = a; ++o; ) { h = this.get(e); k = !h.length; if (h.length === 0) { h = this.create(e).addClass(this.className("jcarousel-item-placeholder")); if (j.length === 0) this.list.prepend(h); else j[d ? "before" : "after"](h); if (this.first !== null && this.options.wrap == "circular" && this.options.size !== null && (e <= 0 || e > this.options.size)) j = this.get(this.index(e)), j.length && (h = this.add(e, j.clone(!0))) } j = h; l = this.dimension(h); if (l === 0) throw Error("jCarousel: No width/height set for items. This will cause an infinite loop. Aborting..."); this.options.wrap != "circular" && this.options.size !== null && e > this.options.size ? m.push(h) : k && (i += l); n += l; if (n >= g) break; e++ } for (h = 0; h < m.length; h++) m[h].remove(); i > 0 && (this.list.css(this.wh, this.dimension(this.list) + i + "px"), d && (b -= i, this.list.css(this.lt, f.intval(this.list.css(this.lt)) - i + "px"))); i = a + o - 1; if (this.options.wrap != "circular" && this.options.size && i > this.options.size) i = this.options.size; if (e > i) { o = 0; e = i; for (n = 0; ++o; ) { h = this.get(e--); if (!h.length) break; n += this.dimension(h); if (n >= g) break } } e = i - o + 1; this.options.wrap != "circular" && e < 1 && (e = 1); if (this.inTail && d) b += this.tail, this.inTail = !1; this.tail = null; if (this.options.wrap != "circular" && i == this.options.size && i - o + 1 >= 1 && (d = f.intval(this.get(i).css(!this.options.vertical ? "marginRight" : "marginBottom")), n - d > g)) this.tail = n - g - d; if (c && a === this.options.size && this.tail) b -= this.tail, this.inTail = !0; for (; a-- > e; ) b += this.dimension(this.get(a)); this.prevFirst = this.first; this.prevLast = this.last; this.first = e; this.last = i; return b }, animate: function (a, c) { if (!this.locked && !this.animating) { this.animating = !0; var b = this, d = function () { b.animating = !1; a === 0 && b.list.css(b.lt, 0); !b.autoStopped && (b.options.wrap == "circular" || b.options.wrap == "both" || b.options.wrap == "last" || b.options.size === null || b.last < b.options.size || b.last == b.options.size && b.tail !== null && !b.inTail) && b.startAuto(); b.buttons(); b.notify("onAfterAnimation"); if (b.options.wrap == "circular" && b.options.size !== null) for (var c = b.prevFirst; c <= b.prevLast; c++) c !== null && !(c >= b.first && c <= b.last) && (c < 1 || c > b.options.size) && b.remove(c) }; this.notify("onBeforeAnimation"); if (!this.options.animation || c === !1) this.list.css(this.lt, a + "px"), d(); else { var f = !this.options.vertical ? this.options.rtl ? { right: a} : { left: a} : { top: a }, d = { duration: this.options.animation, easing: this.options.easing, complete: d }; if (g.isFunction(this.options.animationStepCallback)) d.step = this.options.animationStepCallback; this.list.animate(f, d) } } }, startAuto: function (a) { if (a !== void 0) this.options.auto = a; if (this.options.auto === 0) return this.stopAuto(); if (this.timer === null) { this.autoStopped = !1; var c = this; this.timer = window.setTimeout(function () { c.next() }, this.options.auto * 1E3) } }, stopAuto: function () { this.pauseAuto(); this.autoStopped = !0 }, pauseAuto: function () { if (this.timer !== null) window.clearTimeout(this.timer), this.timer = null }, buttons: function (a, c) { if (a == null && (a = !this.locked && this.options.size !== 0 && (this.options.wrap && this.options.wrap != "first" || this.options.size === null || this.last < this.options.size), !this.locked && (!this.options.wrap || this.options.wrap == "first") && this.options.size !== null && this.last >= this.options.size)) a = this.tail !== null && !this.inTail; if (c == null && (c = !this.locked && this.options.size !== 0 && (this.options.wrap && this.options.wrap != "last" || this.first > 1), !this.locked && (!this.options.wrap || this.options.wrap == "last") && this.options.size !== null && this.first == 1)) c = this.tail !== null && this.inTail; var b = this; this.buttonNext.size() > 0 ? (this.buttonNext.unbind(this.options.buttonNextEvent + ".jcarousel", this.funcNext), a && this.buttonNext.bind(this.options.buttonNextEvent + ".jcarousel", this.funcNext), this.buttonNext[a ? "removeClass" : "addClass"](this.className("jcarousel-next-disabled")).attr("disabled", a ? !1 : !0), this.options.buttonNextCallback !== null && this.buttonNext.data("jcarouselstate") != a && this.buttonNext.each(function () { b.options.buttonNextCallback(b, this, a) }).data("jcarouselstate", a)) : this.options.buttonNextCallback !== null && this.buttonNextState != a && this.options.buttonNextCallback(b, null, a); this.buttonPrev.size() > 0 ? (this.buttonPrev.unbind(this.options.buttonPrevEvent + ".jcarousel", this.funcPrev), c && this.buttonPrev.bind(this.options.buttonPrevEvent + ".jcarousel", this.funcPrev), this.buttonPrev[c ? "removeClass" : "addClass"](this.className("jcarousel-prev-disabled")).attr("disabled", c ? !1 : !0), this.options.buttonPrevCallback !== null && this.buttonPrev.data("jcarouselstate") != c && this.buttonPrev.each(function () { b.options.buttonPrevCallback(b, this, c) }).data("jcarouselstate", c)) : this.options.buttonPrevCallback !== null && this.buttonPrevState != c && this.options.buttonPrevCallback(b, null, c); this.buttonNextState = a; this.buttonPrevState = c }, notify: function (a) { var c = this.prevFirst === null ? "init" : this.prevFirst < this.first ? "next" : "prev"; this.callback("itemLoadCallback", a, c); this.prevFirst !== this.first && (this.callback("itemFirstInCallback", a, c, this.first), this.callback("itemFirstOutCallback", a, c, this.prevFirst)); this.prevLast !== this.last && (this.callback("itemLastInCallback", a, c, this.last), this.callback("itemLastOutCallback", a, c, this.prevLast)); this.callback("itemVisibleInCallback", a, c, this.first, this.last, this.prevFirst, this.prevLast); this.callback("itemVisibleOutCallback", a, c, this.prevFirst, this.prevLast, this.first, this.last) }, callback: function (a, c, b, d, f, j, e) { if (!(this.options[a] == null || typeof this.options[a] != "object" && c != "onAfterAnimation")) { var h = typeof this.options[a] == "object" ? this.options[a][c] : this.options[a]; if (g.isFunction(h)) { var i = this; if (d === void 0) h(i, b, c); else if (f === void 0) this.get(d).each(function () { h(i, this, d, b, c) }); else for (var a = function (a) { i.get(a).each(function () { h(i, this, a, b, c) }) }, k = d; k <= f; k++) k !== null && !(k >= j && k <= e) && a(k) } } }, create: function (a) { return this.format("<li></li>", a) }, format: function (a, c) { for (var a = g(a), b = a.get(0).className.split(" "), d = 0; d < b.length; d++) b[d].indexOf("jcarousel-") != -1 && a.removeClass(b[d]); a.addClass(this.className("jcarousel-item")).addClass(this.className("jcarousel-item-" + c)).css({ "float": this.options.rtl ? "right" : "left", "list-style": "none" }).attr("jcarouselindex", c); return a }, className: function (a) { return a + " " + a + (!this.options.vertical ? "-horizontal" : "-vertical") }, dimension: function (a, c) { var b = g(a); if (c == null) return !this.options.vertical ? b.outerWidth(!0) || f.intval(this.options.itemFallbackDimension) : b.outerHeight(!0) || f.intval(this.options.itemFallbackDimension); else { var d = !this.options.vertical ? c - f.intval(b.css("marginLeft")) - f.intval(b.css("marginRight")) : c - f.intval(b.css("marginTop")) - f.intval(b.css("marginBottom")); g(b).css(this.wh, d + "px"); return this.dimension(b) } }, clipping: function () { return !this.options.vertical ? this.clip[0].offsetWidth - f.intval(this.clip.css("borderLeftWidth")) - f.intval(this.clip.css("borderRightWidth")) : this.clip[0].offsetHeight - f.intval(this.clip.css("borderTopWidth")) - f.intval(this.clip.css("borderBottomWidth")) }, index: function (a, c) { if (c == null) c = this.options.size; return Math.round(((a - 1) / c - Math.floor((a - 1) / c)) * c) + 1 } }); f.extend({ defaults: function (a) { return g.extend(q, a || {}) }, intval: function (a) { a = parseInt(a, 10); return isNaN(a) ? 0 : a }, windowLoaded: function () { m = !0 } }); g.fn.jcarousel = function (a) { if (typeof a == "string") { var c = g(this).data("jcarousel"), b = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); return c[a].apply(c, b) } else return this.each(function () { var b = g(this).data("jcarousel"); b ? (a && g.extend(b.options, a), b.reload()) : g(this).data("jcarousel", new f(this, a)) }) } })(jQuery);
```

Where can I look to find the CSS file? I've searched for the text throughout the whole file structure and cannot find these methods

```
.jcarousel-skin-ie7 .jcarousel-container-horizontal
{
    width:750px;
}

.jcarousel-skin-ie7 .jcarousel-clip-horizontal {
    width:740px; 
}
```

More code...:

```
if(this.options.carousel){
                //default options for carousel
                var carouselDefaults = {vertical:this.options.carouselVertical, initCallback: function(carousel){
                    jQuery(carousel.list).find('img').click(function(e,x) {
                    if(typeof(x) !== 'undefined' && x.how == "auto"){
                        if(self.options.autoPlay == false){
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    var clicked = parseInt(jQuery(this).parents('.jcarousel-item').attr('jcarouselindex'));
                    var last = (jQuery(this).parents('ul').find('li:last').attr('jcarouselindex') == clicked-1) ? true : false;
                    if(!last){
                        clicked = (clicked-2<=0) ? 0 : clicked-2;
                    }
                    clicked++;
                    carousel.scroll(clicked);
                });
            }};
```

I believe this block of code directs to carouseloptions, where I should be making these changes.

> ```
>           var carouselOptions = $.extend({}, carouselDefaults, this.options.carouselOptions || {visible: 6});
>           this.list.jcarousel(carouselOptions);
> ```

```
        }
        if(typeof(this.options.buildFinished) == 'function'){
            this.options.buildFinished(this);
        }
    }, //end setup
```

This is the code being referenced above:

```
 var defaults = {
    autoPlay: true,
    speed: 5000,
    text: { play: "", stop: "", previous: "Previous", next: "Next", loading: "Loading" },
    transition:[1],
    showCaption: true,
    IESafe: false,
    showTooltips: false,
    carousel: false,
    carouselVertical: false,
    animationFinished: null,
    buildFinished: null,
    bindsFinished: null,
    startOn: 0,
    thumbOpacity: 0.4,
    hoverPause: false,
    animationSpeed: 600,
    fadeThumbsIn: false,
```

> ```
>   carouselOptions: {visible: 6},
> ```

```
    thumbChangeEvent: 'click.pikachoose',
    stopOnClick: false
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting number of visible images in jCarousel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122426/setting-number-of-visible-images-in-jcarousel)

Comment: Really? Did you even read the post?

Comment: The answer to your question is in the duplicate. Unless there is something else in your question (that you have changed after I commented) that is new.

Comment: No, it is not. I have exhausted those answers and they did not provide a solution to either my code or if I'm looking in the wrong place. I've made the changes to where I think these answers are pointing (changing visible to 6) but I'm still only getting three pictures. Any actual help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `carouselOptions` have `visible: 6`?

Comment: Carousel options currently has no parameters:

"carouselOptions: {},"

Should this look like:

"carouselOptions: {visible: 6},"?

Comment: Sounds like it yes. Unless you change the code of the plugin itself.

Comment: Ahh, I found more carousel options under my "More code..." section. I'm going to play around with adding it there.

Comment: I've now changed the visible: null to visible: 6 in the first code I posted and added the visible parameter to both carouseloptions I've found (reflected in the last bit of code I posted) and still nothing. I've tried each of these updates separately as well as together.

Comment: I've added more of the code and blocked it out. Still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set it in the javascript options passed as follows:

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({visible: 4});
```

This sets the amount of visible items to four.

See jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xNjwh/168/

**Update**

To find this do a search in your project/file system for `).jcarousel(`.
This will show you where the code is being called, simply add it to the call as above.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm relatively new to this so I appreciate any help. I added some more code...is there where I can add these parameters?

Comment: The closest code I can find that matches I added to my post under "More code...". I'm going to play around with adding it there.

Comment: I've updated and blocked out the code I updated. Still only three items are shown.

Comment: ...so I was playing around on your jsFiddle, and when you revert to an earlier jQuery version, no matter what you put into the visible parameter the carousel will only show 3 items. I believe I've found my problem.

Comment: @dotnetdeveloper well spotted, I've not seen that before. :)