# How to select the quantity of visible items on a responsive jCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

How do I select the quantity of visible items on a jCarousel? I'm using this plugin http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ with this template http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/responsive/

By default a maximum of 3 elements appear no matter how much i change the width of the container, I want to show at least 5 elements.

Answer (score 1):

This setting can be found on the the file jcarousel.responsive.js, here is the Responsive Carousel example on GitHub https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/tree/master/examples/responsive.

The lines

```
if (width >= 600) {
  width = width / 3;
} else if (width >= 350) {
  width = width / 2;
}
```

determine the quantity of items that will be shown on screens larger than 600 and 350 respectively, to show 4 elements on larger screens and only 3 on smaller screens (mobiles) you can use:

```
if (width >= 600) {
  width = width / 4;
} else if (width >= 350) {
  width = width / 3;
}
```

Also note that some users seem to change the setting "visible" ([Setting number of visible images in jCarousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122426/setting-number-of-visible-images-in-jcarousel)) this variable seems to make no changes on the responsive example.